# Mozilla Firefox innerhtml not working

Tags: javascript, firefox, innerhtml

I am facing a problem with firefox and `innerhtml`. I can't figure out why it is not working :/ Chrome, Opera, IE, Safari works fine but Firefox ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head>
    <title>Dokument bez názvu</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styl.css">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
    <style>
        #displaybox
        {
            z-index: 10000;
            filter: alpha(opacity=100); /*older IE*/
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100); /* IE */
            -moz-opacity: 1; /*older Mozilla*/
            -khtml-opacity: 1; /*older Safari*/
            opacity: 1; /*supported by current Mozilla, Safari, and Opera*/
            position: fixed;
            top: 20px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        body
        {
            font-family: Calibri;
        }
        .black_overlay
        {
            visibility: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0%;
            left: 0%;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: black;
            z-index: 1001;
            -moz-opacity: 0.7;
            opacity: .70;
            filter: alpha(opacity=70);
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function clicker() {
            var thediv = document.getElementById('displaybox');
            if (thediv.style.display == "none") {
                thediv.style.display = "";
                thediv.innerHTML = "<embed src='prohlidka.html' height='638' width='1024' ></embed>";
                var thelay = document.getElementById('fade');
                thelay.style.visibility = "visible";
            } else {
                thediv.style.display = "none";
                thediv.innerHTML = '';
                var thelay = document.getElementById('fade');
                thelay.style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
            return false;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fade" class="black_overlay">
    </div>
    <div id="displaybox" style="display: none; overflow: visible">
    </div>
    <a id="otevrit" href='#' onclick='return clicker();'>Virtuální mapa</a>
</body>
```

That's my code, a little bit of css, one function and the body. As I said, other browsers work fine. They normally show `innerhtml` exactly how I need. But Firefox does not, the black overlay works fine. There's no error, no message when I checked javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working properly in mozilla firefox.

I used it in this fiddle : **[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3dcaT/1/)** and just added this line of code :
`console.log($('#displaybox').html());` and i am getting the answer as :
`<embed src="https://www.google.com/" height="638" width="1024">`, which is correct as I had provided the same input.

When i looked at the id `displaybox` in firebug, i was able to see the `embed` code being embedded in that ID.

So there is no problem with the code technically, how ever if you had wanted to open up the page then, your `logic` is `wrong`. You have to use `iframe src` instead of `embed` to open up a page.

Comment: I replaced embed with iframe and it works fine :D thank you so much. It solved my other problems too ^^

Comment: @user3197269 : Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I'ts not the `innerhtml` the problem, it's the `<embed>` tag. It's not meant to open web pages but for example videos. You should instead try with something like `<iframe>`.

Answer (score -1):

I experienced the same problem. The solution is that you can get values from Divs by using .value instead of .innerHTML. This will most lickely work for any kind of browser you will use.